# How to set a white background color for a lightbox in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I need to set the background-color property to white for gallery item.
Now I'm using this code to open the full-screen:

```
this.lightbox.open(0, 'lightbox1', { panelClass: 'fullscreen'})
```

How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the lightbox.css and change styles for the lightbox as fits you, However that will be a bad practice since you are changing the source and that will reflect all lightbox's you are using in your application.

However, you can alter the lightbox style in a specific component using ::ng-deep as follows:

```
::ng-deep lightbox gallery {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but neither modifying the js file of the library and adding the css the background-color doesn't change; any idea about that?

Comment: You should check the DevTools in the browser to see which css class is applying to the lightbox and modify it or you could simply change the background-color of the element containing the lightbox.

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-gallery-lightbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html and try applying in the home.component.css the following:                                                                  
 .container{
  background-color:black
}

Comment: Doesn't work the setting background-color: white! I mean when I'm full screen!

Comment: Try this ::ng-deep lightbox gallery {
  background-color: white !important;
}

Comment: Check this stackblitz.com/edit/… and try applying in the home.component.css the following:  ::ng-deep lightbox gallery {
  background-color: white !important;
}

Comment: Wounderful response! Please share as answer!